# How to output array for Product ID, Price, & Quantity

Tags: javascript, arrays

Need to return an array that has data from table containing the list of Product IDs, unit price and quantity of the user's transaction. Formatted as follows:

```
[{ 
  'id':'#productID1#', 
  'price':'#productPrice1#',
  'quantity':'#productQty1#'
 },
 {
  'id':'#productID2#',
  'price':'#productPrice2#', 
  'quantity':'#productQty2#'
 }]
```

Tried to use quotation marks to add titles (product, price & quantity) as needed as well as apostrophes. However, I am receiving a \ wherever I have apostrophes and am not able to get the desired formatting towards the beginning and end of the variable. Here is what I am outputting:

```
'id\':\'WE119017\',\'price\':\'undefined\',\'quantity\':\'undefined,
 id\':\'WE119012\',\'price\':\'undefined\',\'quantity\':\'undefined,
 id\':\'858191\',\'price\':\'undefined\',\'quantity\':\'undefined,
 id\':\'WE108003\',\'price\':\'undefined\',\'quantity\':\'undefined,
 id\':\'854220\',\'price\':\'undefined\',\'quantity\':\'undefined'
```

Any help would be appreciated as I have no Javascript knowledge or experience and am trying to use online resources to try to figure this out. Thanks!

```
    function() {
    var products = {{Ecommerce Imp Object}};
    return products.reduce(function(arr, prod)
    { return arr.concat("id':'" + prod.id + "'," + "'price':'" + prod.price + "'," + "'quantity'"+":'" + prod.quantity); }, []).join(',');
    }
```

Comment: What is the format of data you are starting with?

Comment: A bit more info would be useful. Where do you want to output it? On the webpage? Developer console? Also, where is `Ecommerce Imp Object` coming from?